# PHPUnit and Laravel: Call to undefined method stdClass::isEmpty()

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to test this controller method.

```
public function handleCreate()
    {
        $offer = new Offer();

        $offer->key_word = $key_word;
        $offer->url = $url;

        $offer->save();

        return Redirect::action('OffersController@index');
    }
```

Here is the test.

```
public function testCreate(){
        Input::replace($input = array('key_word' => 'foo', 'url' => 'http://bar.com'));

        $this->mock->shouldReceive('create')->once()->with($input);

        $this->app->instance('Offer', $this->mock);

        $this->call('POST', 'create');

        $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('/');
    }
```

I'm getting this error when running the test.

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::isEmpty()

Here is the part of the view that is messing it up.

```
@if($offers->isEmpty())
    <p>No offers found.</p>
@else
    ...
@endif
```

I cannot figure out how to add the isEmpty() method to my mock model to get past this error.

I have tried mocking the isEmpty() method with this but it still gave the same error.

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('isEmpty')->once()->andReturn(false);
```

Comment: It appears you don't have an `isEmpty()` method or class, which is why you have the error.

Comment: It is the isEmpty() method that is part of the Eloquent collection class which my mock object is mocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the answer to my question was

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('isEmpty')->once()->andReturn(false);
```

But I'm guessing I had something setup wrong the first time I tried it.